# How to convert Avro structure to SchemaRDD and back?

Tags: apache-spark, avro

Is there a way to convert [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/) structure to [SchemaRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SchemaRDD.html)? I see an example for JavaRDD in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2736, but was unable to find anything to create SchemaRDD.

There is a link which shows to how to convert a SchemaRDD to Avro, but I wanted to know if there is something provided inside Spark 1.1

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3350

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a separate package that allows you to do that: https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro

As of now it allows you to do both Avro -> SparkSQL and SparkSQL -> Avro.

It's unlikely that it will be added to Spark itself to keep the scope of the project under control, but there are many useful Spark packages being developed outside of Spark. See more at http://spark-packages.org/